# argocd login is failing with "received the unexpected content-type" error

Tags: argocd

When attempting to login using CLI, I get an error

```
FATA[0004] rpc error: code = Internal desc = transport: received the unexpected content-type "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
```

Here is our Ingress config:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: argocd-server-ingress
  namespace: argocd
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - argocd.foo.dev
      secretName: argocd-foo-dev-tls
  rules:
    - host: argocd.foo.dev
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: argocd-server
            servicePort: https
          path: /
```

The web UI works as expected.

I am using command:

```
argocd login argocd.foo.dev
```

What is missing?

Comment: Did you ever get this working (without requiring the `--grpc-web` flag on client commands)?

Answer (score 2):

While I am not 100% what is the reason for the above error, using `--grpc-web` works around it:

```
argocd login argocd.foo.dev --grpc-web
```

Documentation says that this flag is needed when HTTP2 is not supported:

> Enables gRPC-web protocol. Useful if Argo CD server is behind proxy which does not support HTTP2.

In our case, our ingress controller is [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx) and it does support [http2](/questions/tagged/http2).

Answer (score 1):

You need to login first:

```
argocd login localhost:8080
```

Comment: This applies only to argocd login command run on the server or kubernetes pod.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `--insecure` flag. For example:

`argocd login $ARGOCD_HOST:$ARGOCD_PORT --insecure --username $ARGOCD_ADMIN_USER --password $ARGOCD_ADMIN_PASSWORD`

Answer (score 0):

I have disabled strict tls between argocd-server and dex-server, logged in with Okta using the following command:

> argocd login  --username  --grpc-web-root-path / --sso --skip-test-tls

With static username and password

> argocd login  --username  --password  --grpc-web-root-path / --sso --skip-test-tls